# Ionic Progressive Web App captured image is mirrored

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4, progressive-web-apps

Ionic Progressive Web App captured image using `Camera.getPhoto()` is mirrored.

The following is the sample code.

```
const capturedPhoto = await Camera.getPhoto({
  resultType: CameraResultType.Base64,
  source: CameraSource.Camera,
  direction: CameraDirection.Front,
});
```

Please let me know anyone also facing this issue.

Thank you...!

Comment: have you read this one =>  https://github.com/ionic-team/pwa-elements/issues/11#issuecomment-588042687

Comment: @lussac I tried but not working

Comment: how about using html5 like this person suggest => https://github.com/ionic-team/pwa-elements/issues/11#issuecomment-597129425 its seems ionic still have an issue with camera plugin for web app